# Entity Framwork v.7.0.9 Many to Many Relationship Adding a additional Column to Junction Table

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, many-to-many

BaseModel

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;

namespace SelfService.Portal.Core.API.Models
{
    public class BaseModel
    {
        [Column(Order = 0)]
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public Guid Id { get; set; }

        [Column(Order = 50)]
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Computed)]
        public DateTime Modified { get; set; }
        [Column(Order = 51)]
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Computed)]
        public string ModifiedBy { get; set; }
        [Column(Order = 52)]
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public DateTime Created { get; set; }
        [Column(Order = 53)]
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public string CreatedBy { get; set; }
    }
}
```

OptionModel

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;

namespace SelfService.Portal.Core.API.Models
{
    public class OptionModel : BaseModel
    {
        [Column(Order = 1)]
        public string Name { get; set; }
        [Column(Order = 2)]
        public string OptionType { get; set; }
        [Column(Order = 3)]
        public string OptionValue { get; set; }

        public ICollection<TemplateModel> Templates { get; set; }
    }
}
```

TemplateModel

```
using Microsoft.Identity.Client;
using System.Text.Json.Serialization;

namespace SelfService.Portal.Core.API.Models
{
    public class TemplateModel : BaseModel
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Version { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public string JSONData { get; set; }
        
        public ICollection<OptionModel> Options { get; set; }
    }
        
}
```

DataContext

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

            /* Rename Junction Table Option -> Template */
            modelBuilder.Entity<TemplateModel>()
                .HasMany(o => o.Options)
                .WithMany(d => d.Templates)
                .UsingEntity(
                    "TemplateOptions",
                    l => l.HasOne(typeof(TemplateModel)).WithMany().HasForeignKey("TemplateId").HasPrincipalKey(nameof(TemplateModel.Id)),
                    r => r.HasOne(typeof(OptionModel)).WithMany().HasForeignKey("OptionId").HasPrincipalKey(nameof(OptionModel.Id)),
                    j => j.HasKey("EnvironmentId", "DomainId")
                );
        }
```

This setting works, but now I want to add another column in the Junction Table TemplateOptions called "Value". Is this possible and if so how?

Current result in the SQL Database

TemplateId | OptionId

Desired result

TemplateId | OptionId | Value

Answer (score 0):

As written in [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships/many-to-many#many-to-many-and-join-table-with-payload) you can create explicit type for junction table and use it:

```cs
public class TemplateOption
{
    public int TemplateId { get; set; }
    public int OptionId { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }

    public TemplateModel Template { get; set; }
    public OptionModel Option { get; set; }
}

public class OptionModel : BaseModel
{
   // ...
   public ICollection<TemplateOption> TemplateOptions{ get; set; }
}

public class TemplateModel : BaseModel
{
   // ...
   public ICollection<TemplateOption> TemplateOptions{ get; set; }
}
```

As far as I remember it should be already fully qualified relationship (with corresponding `DbSet` added) but if needed you can set it up with Fluent API:

```cs
modelBuilder.Entity<TemplateModel>()
    .HasMany(o => o.Options)
    .WithMany(d => d.Templates)
    .UsingEntity<TemplateOption>(TemplateOptions", /* if needed ... */);
```

Comment: Try again. Join entity having collections, really?

Comment: @IvanStoev yep, stupid me, was copying from old playground which was reworked =) Thank you!